# Почтовик на php

Tags: php, email

Добрый день.

Есть ли возможность или какой готовый почтовик на php. Интересует не только отправка почты (это и так понятно), но, и самое главное, это получать и просматривать почту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендую http://roundcube.net/
Намного гибче squirrelmail, симпатичнее, на аяксе, ну и вообще - человечнее.

Comment: слева есть кнопочка "принят ответ" - рекомендую учиться ее использовать )

Answer (score 1):

[SquirrelMail](http://www.squirrelmail.org/) - ответ на ваш вопрос.